# SAS %DO %UNTIL compare two variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset A1 as below.

```
ID COL1    COL2    COL3  COL4  COL5.....
A  04JAN21 05JAN21 16JAN21  01FEB21 06FEB21....
B  19DEC20  01JAN21  02JAN21  18JAN21 31MAR21....
C ........
D ........`
```

ID column is unique and COL1, COL2...are SAS Date9. format. I am trying to compare (COLi)+33 days and COL(i+3). If (COLi)+33 days>COL(i+3), it will count 1.

My SAS CODE is below:

```
DATA _NULL_；
    SET A1;
    CALL SYMPUT('NO',LEFT(PUT(_N_,6.)));
RUN;
%MACRO TEST();
DATA A2;
    SET A1;
    %DO i=1 %TO &NO.;
       z=0;
    %DO %UNTIL(%SYSFUNC(COL%eval(&j+3))=.);
   %IF %SYSFUNC(COL%eval(&j+3))<INTNX('day',COL&j,33) %THEN %DO;
   %LET z=%eval(z+1);
    %END;
   %END;
  %END;
RUN;
%MEND;
%TEST;
```

Above example, A case has case 1 & 4, case 2 & 5, counting 2 times.
B case only has case 1 & 4.

Pls help see what syntax error I have. Many thanks.

Comment: What you trying to do? Why are you using macro code instead of regular SAS code? Show an example of the SAS code that you want the macro code to generate. What parts of  the SAS code are you trying to use the macro pre-processor to create?

Comment: Use an `ARRAY` statement to make the variables addressable via `array-name[index]`.  No need for macro. `DIM(array-name)` would replace your `&NO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro code is for generating code, not manipulating data.

It is not clear what you are trying to count, but you probably have no need to generate code.  Just loop over an array to perform your testing.

```
DATA A2;
  SET A1;
  array col col1-col5 ;
  z=0;
  do j=1 to dim(col)-3;
    if col[j+3] < col[j]+33 then z=z+1;
  end;
RUN;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly. Each ID may have different numbers of COLs. For example, case A may have 5 dates, case B may have 38 dates, case C may have 123 dates...etc. So, I tried to use do until when the COL(i+3) is missing then quit the loop.

Comment: That is not possible. A dataset has a fixed number of variables.  Are you saying you want to run a similar analysis against different datasets that have a different number of variables?

Comment: If only the m out of N columns actually have dates just adjust the counting logic to handle missing values properly.  Perhaps `if . < col[j+3] < col[j]+33 then z=z+1;`